# Search functionality through Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, full-text-search

I am working on some website which is build up in Zend Framework. I have a search functionality with fulltext index search. I want to build the search functionality like if i search for "Computers", the search result should contain records having "Computers" or "Computer" or "Computing". If i search for "technology" result should come with records having "technology" or "technologies". If i search "Leukemia" result should come with records having "Leukemia" or "Blood cancer".
Database i am using is MYSQL MyIsam.

I want to know, How can we do this?

or

is there any plugin for the functionality i am looking for?

Thanks

Comment: No body is there to answer?

Answer (score 0):

For that type of complex searching, I wouldn't use the database. I would recommend using Lucene, which Zend has a library for (Zend_Search_Lucene). Lucene allows you to perform complex searches with no hit on the database, it's all file based.

An example of how this could help, you could add two Lucene documents, one for Leukemia and one for Lymphoma, and tag each with "Blood cancer". This way, searching for "Blood cancer" would return both results, as well as searching for one could return the other.

I can't get into all the details here, but Lucene is extremly fast and powerful, you can read more on it here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html